# Как правильно попросить открыть пластиковое окно для проветривания?

Tags: стилистика

Здравствуйте, интересует такой вопрос. Вот со старыми деревянными окнами всё ясно - открыть форточку. А как быть с пластиковыми, которые для проветривания открываются вниз, и никакой форточки там нет, хотя я всегда слышу именно просьбу "открыть форточку", но мне кажется, это неправильно. Сказать "приоткрыть" тоже не всегда хорошо - часто из контекста не ясно, как именно нужно это сделать. Сам говорю "открой плашмя", но этот вариант мне тоже кажется сомнительным.
А как вы считаете или как сами говорите?
Заранее спасибо и прошу прощение за некоторую сумбурность.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если официально, то можно попросить открыть [фрамугу](http://enc-dic.com/official/Framuga-2495.html), правда в обычной речи подобное использовать не советовал бы, так как могут неправильно понять.

*Открыть форточку* тоже возможно, так как форточкой могут называть не только дверцу на раме, но и вообще любое небольшое отверстие для каких-либо целей (см. [словарь Ефремовой](http://enc-dic.com/efremova/Fortochka-115708.html).

Сам я в таких случаях прошу приоткрыть окно сверху, но, вообще, подобные способы открывания явление сравнительно недавнее и устоявшегося определения для данного действия ещё не сложилось, так что может быть даже ваше *открыть плашмя* впоследствии станет литературным.

Answer (score 1):

Я всегда говорю «открыть окно». Об остальном даже и не слышал. Если у окна нет форточки, то говорить «откройте форточку» неправильно и нелогично. :)

Comment: Вот и мне так думается, что вариант с "форточка" не верен совершенно точно. Осталось определиться с обозначением действия, когда оно открывается, но не настежь (не слева направо)

Answer (score 0):

По сути Вы открываете окно, т. к. самой форточки в нем нет. Поэтому правильно: Откройте окно, чтобы проветрить комнату (в том случае, если нужно проветрить  помещение). Если вас смущает способ открытия окна, то надо отметить, что при просьбе это никак не отражается.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Но как это лучше сделать с точки зрения красоты речи? Просьба открыть окно почти всегда понимается как просьбу открыть его настежь. А нужно "плашмя", вот у меня и возникли сомнения.

Comment: Если окно открывается плашмя, по-другому его открыть не смогут. По сути плашмя - это тоже настежь. Ведь оба окна открыты полностью. Можете сказать: приоткройте окно. Почему вас не устраивает этот вариант? Что значит ''из контекста не ясно"?

Comment: Из контекста не ясно может быть вот почему: на улице не жара, но и не холод - типичная погода в моём регионе. И просьба приоткрыть окно требует уточнения, каким образом его открыть (оно открывается и настежь, и вниз, и есть ещё микропроветривание - но с ним вопросов нет)..

Comment: Про  микропроветривание  - не слышал. Если окно открывается несколькими способами, в любом случае Вам придется уточнить, каким способом Вы хотите, чтобы открыли окно. Можете сказать: Откройте/приоткройте окно. А затем пояснить, каким способом вам нужно, чтобы открыли окно. Это же не письменная речь, чтобы была красота речи, лаконичность.

Comment: Да, окна кругом преимущественно такие многорежимные. Вот о том, как бы уточнить, не абы как, а нормально,  я и спросил :) К тому же, речь может быть и письменная, кто знает, вдруг придётся описывать этот процесс.

Comment: В устной речи сказать можно так: Открой/приоткрой окно влево, вправо, так, чтобы проветрить. В письменной речи же речи используют более официальный язык. Все зависит от того, что Вы пишите.

Comment: «Более официальный»? :)

Comment: "Более официальный" язык мне тоже не совсем понятен :) Господа, а вы с такими окнами никогда не сталкивались? (смайлик, выражающий отчаяние). Просто чувствую себя так, будто спрашиваю о явлении с какой-то другой планеты. Не знаю даже, как описать. Сверху вниз оно открывается под углом, а не "скользит по рельсам". Ну и вбок как обычное окно. Второе действие - открыть настежь. А как бы вы описали первое?

Comment: Да как хотите, так и говорите. Разговорный язык - свободный. Если человек знает, как пользоваться этим окном, он вас поймет, если нет - вам придется самому ему показать. А там уже и слова не нужны. Он сам увидит. ))

Comment: Tagirix , что вас смутило. Письменная речь всегда более официальна, чем разговорная. Там нужна лаконичность, четкость.

Comment: Серж, это понятно. Вот говорят преимущественно "открыть форточку", хотя форточки там нет, ну да я уже писал об этом. Просто хотелось бы узнать, какие возможны варианты. Пока что мой собственный (я его от посторонних людей ни разу не слышал) вариант "плашмя" кажется более или менее пригодным. У меня было подозрение, что этот явление целая беда неизученная :)

Comment: Сергей, если вам нужно, чтобы окно открыли плашмя,можете так и сказать. Ошибкой это не будет. . Я опять повторюсь: в разговорной речи можно излагать свои мысли свободно. Когда вы открываете форточку, вы же не задумываетесь, как она открывается.

Answer (score 0):

Открыть полностью — потянуть за створку до упора. Приоткрыть (сбоку) — отворить где-то на четверть. Открыть сверху — приоткрыть с наклоном. Оставить щель или поставить на фиксатор — оставить, поставить или подставить. «Сидеть» ещё потом, но это потом, после «Прикрыть» или «Закрыть».

Answer (score 0):

Какой интересный вопрос.
Я говорю "открой на форточку" (по аналогии с "наполовину", "на четверть"). Не очень грамотно, но понятно.